# Memory allocated pointer and a copy pointer in a template

Tags: c++

I want to know what is the difference between using the following two pointers in a template:

Lets assume that I allocated a memory as the following:

```
int* myPtr = new int[10];
int* anotherPtr = myPtr;
```

Now, I passed "myPtr" and "anotherPtr" to some functions:

```
doSomthing(myPtr, status);
doAnotherThing(anotherPtr, status);
```

inside the above two functions I am using this parameter to define a template class, such as:

```
tResource<int>* m_resourcePtr1;
tResource<int>* m_resourcePtr2;
m_resourcePtr1 = new tResource<int> (anotherPtr);
m_resourcePtr2 = new tResource<int> (myPtr);
```

Is there is any difference between resourcePtr1 and resourcePtr2?

Comment: @Bassam There seems to be some reason behind your question. If you'll explain why you're asking the question maybe it will be easier to give an answer that is meaningful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. It depends on what tResource does with the pointers. It could be that tResource's constructor simply ignores the pointer parameter and always behaves the same. Since you have not given any detail on what tResource is or does, we cannot be any more specific than saying that `m_resourcePtr1 != m_resourcePtr2`

Comment: +1: The only strictly correct answer so far (although the others will probably end up being correct when the OP clarifies his question)

Comment: @Paul: Did you even read this answer? How do you know that `(anotherPtr == myPtr) => (m_resourcePtr1 == m_resourcePtr2)` when you don't know what `tResource` is?

Comment: @Tomalak Unless `tResource` does some very odd thing, like using the address of the pointer itself, or has some internal state that changes between calls, the objects will be the same. Even if the data that the pointers point to is copied (meaning the two `tResource` objects will have different copies of it), the objects will still be essentially the same.

Comment: @Tomalak Notice the 'essentially'. Read: unless the class does some hacky thing, it should behave the same provided it acts upon the same data, even if that data is actually two copies in two different locations. For `operator==` to actually return true, you still have to redefine it.

Comment: @Paul: Maybe it _is_ doing some hacky thing. Then your answer is incorrect and you downvoted the only answer that acknowledged the possibility.

Comment: @Paul, not if the tResource constructor takes a pointer reference as an argument... :)

Comment: tResource<int> is a class that will contain a pointer (of type int* in this case) this template act as a leaf in a tree.
One of the answers from "Tomalak Geret'kal" confirmed something in my mind:
"The fact that one pointer is the one you used when you first created the array doesn't make it any different from other pointers."

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is any different between resourcePtr1 and resourcePtr2.

These two objects will not be equivalent only if you use some `static` state when constructing the object in the constructor, and you update it everytime an object is created, or you use some global states, or any other means of state, that doesn't depend on the arguments of the constructor, such as `rand()` or user-input.

Otherwise, both objects will be equivalent, because both are built from the exactly same piece of information called`myPtr`.

Also, `anotherPtr` is pointing to the same object as does `myPtr`, so they're same. If you `delete myPtr`, `anotherPtr` will become invalid.

So, the following

```
m_resourcePtr1 = new tResource<int> (anotherPtr);
m_resourcePtr2 = new tResource<int> (myPtr);
```

is equivalent to this,

```
m_resourcePtr1 = new tResource<int> (myPtr);
m_resourcePtr2 = new tResource<int> (myPtr);
```

Now ask yourself, is there any difference between `m_resourcePtr1` and `m_resourcePtr2`?   The answer is pretty much straightforward.

Comment: You can't guarantee that unless you know what `tResource` is.

Comment: The answer is still "who knows"? What if there's some auto-incrementing counter inside `tResource`? The two objects are immediately different, and that's just a trivial example!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I added few more text.

Comment: New counter-example: a member variable set to `rand()`, or that takes any user input, or any input from its environment.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Yeah. Things of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference; there's no way for the constructor to differentiate between the two int-pointers — in fact, there's no difference between them to begin with, as they both point to the same array. The fact that one pointer is the one you used when you first created the array doesn't make it any different from other pointers.

However, note that your code is wrong: if what you want to do is to pass a pointer to an array, you should also pass the size of the array along with it (`10`, in this case). How else would you know how many ints the array contains?

Comment: The class may have other state, _not_ taken directly from the ctor argument, that makes the two objects different. You just don't know enough about the class to be making these guarantees.

Comment: @Tomalak Its pretty clear that the OP is asking if there's any difference between the pointers; it reasonable to assume that there's nothing of interest in `tResource`.

Comment: You know what assuming does, don't you?

Comment: @Tomalak It depends on the context, doesn't it? If I was asked to provide full definitions for every question I post on SO, even when they are not necessary, I wouldn't be using this site.

Comment: On the contrary: a good question contains a minimal but _complete_ testcase. This one contains a blackbox at the same time as being a question about the behaviour of that blackbox, and as such it is not possible to reason about it in full; making assumptions and generalisations, potentially leading to the answer being 100% incorrect without a disclaimer, is dangerous.